# What does it mean for an architectural style to be document-centric?

Tags: architecture, rest, nosql

I heard it said that [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is "document-centric". Unclear what this meant, I began poking around and found the term **document-oriented** being used of [databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database), particularly NoSQL databases, and in contrast to a barebones [key-value store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076781/834176). Thus it seems that documented-orientation of databases has to do with their internal representations being JSON or XML; I saw on the Wikipedia page that many document-oriented databases claim to support a RESTful API, but not having experience with any NoSQL databases and also being new to REST, I'm unsure what that means (the database itself is directly accessible through a service?); and anyway, as far as I know, REST does not constrain the underlying data model of an application, but only its [service contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture#Programmatic_service_contract).

So what does it mean to say that REST is document-centric/oriented? Does it mean that REST constrains a service to use JSON or XML in its contract? Does it mean that REST is more friendly towards NoSQL databases than conventional relational databases?

Comment: They just really didn't want to use the word object because it's already poisoned (for good reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document-centric means that it doesn't require static schema. This is usually done by saving data in platform-agnostic format using many data-serializing methods like JSON and XML. This allows easy development and versioning, but makes it harder to validate each object.

Comment: For robustness: So what would be the contrasting term, when a schema is required? Are there examples of a SOA architecture that is not document-centric?

Comment: @Kazark Oposite is when transfer/persistence requires defined schema. For databases, this is represented by relational model. For web services it is whole SOAP alongside it's WSDL.

Comment: Okay, great. Sometimes the contrast is what is needed for a clearer understanding. If you like, maybe you can add that to your answer.